# Figaro "undefined method `require_keys' for Figaro:Module (NoMethodError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, environment-variables

In my `config/initializers/figaro.rb`

I put:

```
Figaro.require_keys("MANDRILL_API_KEY")
```

but got the following when running `rails s`:

```
Exiting
/Users/guycao/code/oms_on_rails/config/initializers/figaro.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `require_keys' for Figaro:Module (NoMethodError)
        from /Users/guycao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
        from /Users/guycao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
        from /Users/guycao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/guycao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'

        ...
```

Here are my configs:
Figaro version - 0.7.0
Ruby version - ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
Rails version - 4.1.2

For your information, the environmental variable does exist in the `application.yml`
but even if it didn't exist, it shouldn't complain about not being able to find the `require_keys` method.

Am I missing something? I tried `require "figaro"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Figaro.require_keys` was added in version 1.0. It was previously called `Figaro.require`. Either upgrade figaro to 1.x or use the `require` method.

https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro/blame/master/CHANGELOG.md#L6